# Check nested array structure in mock class

Tags: mocking, phpunit, multidimensional-array

I've written a method that basically looks like this:

```
public function collectData($input, FooInterface $foo) {
   $data = array();
   $data['products']['name'] = $this->some_method();
   if(empty($input['bar'])) {
       $data['products']['type'] = "Baz";
   }
   // hundreds of calls later
   $foo->persist($data);
}
```

Now I'd like to unit test the `collectData` method to check if values in `$data` are set for certain inputs. For object parameters I'd normally use a mock like this:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('FooInterface');
$mock->expects($this->once())
             ->method('persist')
             ->with($this->identicalTo($expectedObject));
```

But how would I test for certain nested array keys (for example, if `$data['products']['prices']['taxgroup']` is 1), ignoring all other keys that might be in the array? Does PHPUnit or Mockery provide such checks? Or could they easily extended to provide such a check?

Or is it better to do what I'm doing at the moment: create my own `FooClassMock` class that implements `FooInterface` and just stores the data in the `persist` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, there is a way - I can create my own [constraint class](https://gist.github.com/gbirke/5115086). After that, it's easy:

```
$constraint = new NestedArrayConstraint(
    array('products', 'prices', 'taxgroup'),
    $this->equalTo(1)
);
$mock = $this->getMock('FooInterface', array('persist'));
$mock->expects($this->once())
             ->method('persist')
             ->with($constraint);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one more option, but only if you use PHPUnit >= 3.7. There is a callback assertion and you can use it like this:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('FooInterface', array('persist');
$mock->expects($this->once())
         ->method('persist')
         ->with($this->callback(function($object) {
             // here you can do your own complex assertions

             return true|false;
         }));
```

Here is more details:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/206